# Text input not showing in Firefox.

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following input field :

[image]

Its's all working fine in google chrome but when i check this in firefox i get the following result :

[image]

There is text in it but the input field stays white.

[image]

This is the css that is being used. I really have no idea how to fix this.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you provide some working example for us? Fiddle, codepen or plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you check this css

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

Comment: The user was referring to text inputted into the text box, not the placeholder attribute